# HashSet adds duplicate entries despite implementing both hashCode() and equals()

Tags: java

I have the following class:

```
class Point
{
     double x, y;

     // .... constructor and other functions here

     public boolean equals(Point p)
     {
         if(p==null) return(false);
         return(x==p.x && y==p.y);
     }

    public int hashCode()
    {
        int result=17;

        long c1=Double.doubleToLongBits(x);
        long c2=Double.doubleToLongBits(y);

        int ci1=(int)(c1 ^ (c1 >>> 32));
        int ci2=(int)(c2 ^ (c2 >>> 32));

        result = 31 * result + ci1;
        result = 31 * result + ci2;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Now, if I write the following code:

```
    Point x=new Point(11,7);
    Point y=new Point(11,7);

    System.out.println("hash-code of x=" + x.hashCode());
    System.out.println("hash-code of y=" + y.hashCode());
    System.out.println("x.equals(y) = " + x.equals(y));
    System.out.println("x==y = " + (x==y));

    java.util.HashSet<Point> s=new java.util.HashSet<Point>();
    s.add(x);
    System.out.println("Contains "+y.toString()+" = "+s.contains(y));
    s.add(y);
    System.out.println("Set size: "+s.size());
    java.util.Iterator<Point> itr=s.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()) System.out.println(itr.next().toString());
```

I am getting the following output:

```
hash-code of x=79052753
hash-code of y=79052753
x.equals(y) = true
x==y = false
Contains (11.0,7.0) = false
Set size: 2
(11.0,7.0)
(11.0,7.0)
```

Please help me in understanding why contains() returns false (even after equals() and hashCode() return the same value) and how can I rectify this (i.e. preventing Java from adding duplicate elements). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow! It would be so great If all questions are so clear and understandable, and have code and outputs for reproducing. Well done!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not overriding the equals method in Object.

The signature of equals method is:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
```

and not

```
public boolean equals(Point obj)
```

And please do not compare double values using ==. You should use Double.equals instead.

Comment: Value of simple types can be compared using ==

Comment: @SergeyMorozov - No. Using == for floating point comparisons is not recommended. It is not safe.

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem.

As far as comparison is concerned, according to the documentation, Double.equals returns false when -0.0 and +0.0 are being compared; so I think I would stick to == than Double.equals().

Comment: @aetheria - double x = 1.0/3.0; double y = 1 - (2.0/3.0);if (x == y) System.out.println("Equal");

What do you think will the output be?

Comment: @user3493289 Ultimately, for more robust implementations, we do have to use +/- delta differences, i.e. abs(x1-x2) <= delta, which is the best we can hope for while checking real values

Comment: @user1637645 - i can live with implementations that use delta differences because that shows that people are aware of the issues with double values. But whenever i see code that uses == on double, i tend to be suspicious

Comment: @user1637645 While I generally agree that one should be careful with floating point comparisons and `==`, the delta-based comparison may **NOT** be used for the implementation of an `equals` method: The `equals` method has to be *transitive*. Consider (only for illustrating the problem) values of `x=1`, `y=2` and `z=3`. With a delta of 1.5, you will have `x.equals(y)` and `y.equals(z)`, but `x.equals(z)` will *not* hold. This violates the contract of `equals`.

Answer (score 8):

You have changed the method signature from `Object.equals(Object)`, so you aren't correctly overriding `equals`. I suggest you use the `@Override` annotation to catch this class of bugs. Your method should look something like,

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
     if (this == o) {
         return true;
     }
     if (o instanceof Point) {
         Point p = (Point) o;
         return(x==p.x && y==p.y);
     }
     return false;
}
```

Comment: I have changed my code and overrode it correctly this time and it solved my problem. Thanks a lot.